# Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid data has been used to update the list item. "

Tags: 2013, list, development, powershell

I have an announcement list, where i need to populate it with some old data we have on emails, documents, etc. so i did the following:-

1.inside our Team site i added a new "Announcement list" .
2.then i wrote the following power-shell, to be able to add announcement items using our data, as follow:-

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $web = get-spweb "http://servername/"
PS C:\Windows\system32> $list = $web.lists["News & Announcements"]
PS C:\Windows\system32> $newItem = $list.items.Add();
PS C:\Windows\system32> $newItem["Title"] = "123";
PS C:\Windows\system32> $newItem["Modified"] = "8/30/2015";
PS C:\Windows\system32> $newItem["Created"] = "6/30/2015";
PS C:\Windows\system32> $newItem["Body"] = "123456789 123456789";
PS C:\Windows\system32> $newItem["Editor"] = "test.user";
PS C:\Windows\system32> $newItem["Author"] = "test.user";
PS C:\Windows\system32> $newItem.Update();
```

but i got this error :-

> Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid data has
>   been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update
>   may be read only." At line:1 char:1
>   + $newItem.Update();
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SPException

so can anyone advice on this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different points to note:

1. Use `$list.AddItem()` instead of `$list.items.Add()`. Much much better for performances.
2. You cannot set the `Modified`, `Created`, `Author` and `Editor` fields with a call to `Update`. You need to call the method `UpdateOverwriteVersion` instead.
3. In datetime fields (`Modified`, `Created`), you need to set actual `DateTime` values, e.g. `New-Object System.DateTime(2015, 8, 30)`
   EDIT: actually, this is true only in pure C# code... for PowerShell, you need to pass a string, see for instance http://sharepointcherie.blogspot.fr/2014/02/powershell-error-when-inserting-dates.html.
4. In users fields (`Author`, `Editor`), you need to set an `SPUser` object. You can get an `SPUser` object by using `SPWeb.EnsureUser()` method, e.g. `$user = $web.EnsureUser("domain\LoginName")`

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $web = Get-SPWeb "http://servername/"  
PS C:\Windows\system32> $list = $web.Lists["News & Announcements"]  
PS C:\Windows\system32> $newItem = $List.AddItem()  
PS C:\Windows\system32> $newItem["Title"] = "123"  
PS C:\Windows\system32> $newItem["Body"] = "123456789 123456789"  
PS C:\Windows\system32> $newItem["Modified"] = "8/30/2015"  
PS C:\Windows\system32> $newItem["Created"] = "6/30/2015"  
PS C:\Windows\system32> $user = $web.EnsureUser("domain\test.user")  
PS C:\Windows\system32> $newItem["Editor"] = $user  
PS C:\Windows\system32> $newItem["Author"] = $user  
PS C:\Windows\system32> $newItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but i got this error "_Specified cast is not valid.
At line:1 char:1
+ $newItem["Modified"] = New-Object System.DateTime(2015, 8, 30)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], InvalidCastException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidCastException_" on the 'Modified' & on the 'Created' fields

Comment: Try `Get-Date "10/10/2015"` instead of `New-Object System.DateTime(2015, 8, 30)`

Comment: You confirm: `Modified` and `Created` are the standard SP fields, not custom ones you've created with these display names?

Comment: yes Modified & Created are the built-in columns,, those are the display+internal names... now when i try the following "_$newItem["Modified"] = Get-Date "10/10/2016"_" i will get this error "_Specified cast is not valid.
At line:1 char:1
+ $newItem["Created"] = Get-Date "10/10/2015"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], InvalidCastException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidCastException_"

Comment: OK, sorry for the error, was still thinking "C#"... PowerShell actually needs dates as strings, as you initially wrote. I corrected the script.

Comment: thanks for the update but `(New-Object System.DateTime(2015, 8, 30)).ToString()` will raise the following error:-  `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
At line:1 char:1
+ $newItem["Modified"] = (New-Object System.DateTime(2015, 8, 30)).ToString()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], FormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.FormatException` for both created and modified

Comment: OK, back to your original code, with pure strings... Maybe the `.ToString()` call was not formatting the date as a correct date as per the SP site locale... who knows? Long story short: try with the exact string you had initially, and let me know the result (I updated my answer).

Comment: ok it worked fine